# Cannot send message to other end using PeerJs connection

Tags: javascript, angular, webrtc

What I am trying to achieve is building a WebRtc application to support data and video exchange using PeerJs. My component.ts looks something like this:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.peer = new Peer();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.mypeerid = this.peer.id;
    },3000);
    this.peer.on('connection', function(conn) {
       conn.on('data', function(data){
           console.log(data);
       });
    });
  }

  connect(){
    var conn = this.peer.connect(this.secondId.nativeElement.value);
    console.log(conn);
    conn.on('open', function(){
      conn.send('Message from that id');
    });
  }
```

The component.html looks like:

```html
<h1>My id - {{mypeerid}}</h1>
<input type="text" #secondId>
<button (click)="connect()">Connect</button>
```

I would mention along with this that I have added the statement **declare var Peer: any** in typings.d.ts

The code runs well but unfortunately, **conn.send('Message from that id')** doesn't send console.log message at the other end.

Comment: How did you add peerjs ?? in index.html or angular.json

Comment: I have added this to the index.html:   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/peerjs/0.3.9/peer.min.js"></script>. Also I would add that I removed the key param while creating the peer object and this worked without an error but I can not see the message at the other end :/